# When sum of two Poisson variables is not Poisson

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent Poisson random variables, then $X+Y$ is Poisson. We also know that sum of two dependent Poisson variables might result in another Poisson variable.

My question is: what would be the counterexample (not the rigorous proof which might exist) that negates the claim that sum of two Poissons, irrespective of their dependency,  would always result in Poisson.

Comment: What about the sum of a Poisson and itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expected value of a Poisson random variable is equal to its variance.

Now just take two Poisson random variables with parameters $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ with non-vanishing covariance.  Then their sum can’t be Poisson as the sum’s expected value is $\lambda_1+\lambda_2$ but the sum’s variance  doesn’t equal $\lambda_1+\lambda_2$.

Comment: Just to make it clear that such distributions of a pair of random variables do exist, consider three positive numbers $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ with $\alpha+\beta=\lambda_1$ and $\beta+\gamma=\lambda_2.$ Then let $A, B, C$ be independent Poisson-distributed random variables with expected values $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ respectively. Let $X=A+B$ and let $Y=B+C.$ Then $X\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda_1)$ and $Y\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda_2). \qquad$

Answer (score 5):

If $X\sim \mathcal{P}(\lambda)$, then $$\Bbb P(X+X=1)=0$$
Therefore $X+X$ does not follow a Poisson distribution.

Comment: Yes, $2X$ is not a Poisson. Thanks

Comment: Your example is not a sum of random variables but a scaled random variable instead.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe it is both. Scaling by an *integer* is also the result of a sum.

Comment: Definitely not.  Take a dice, e.g. Here $2X$ takes the values $2,4,6,8,10,12$ but $X_1+X_2$ takes all integer values from $2$ to $12$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe you know that this is not what I mean. The OP didn't say that X and Y shouldn't be related.